# How to access values from panels in Red language

Tags: object, rebol, red

I am using following code to find products of 2 series of numbers and then to find sum of these products:

```
  make-row: func [][
    compose [
        t1: text "N1:"
        f1: field 
        t2: text "N2: "
        f2: field
        t3: text "Product: "
        t4: text ""
        b: button "Get product" [
            x: face/extra/2/text          
            y: face/extra/4/text
            z: (to-integer x) * (to-integer y)
            face/extra/6/text: rejoin [z]]
        do [b/extra: reduce [t1 f1 t2 f2 t3 t4]] ]  ]

  view compose [
        (make-row) return 
        (make-row) return
    b: button "Calculate" [t2/text: "..to be given"]
    t1: text "Sum of products:"
    t2: text ""                       ; NEED TO GET SUM OF ALL PRODUCTS IN ABOVE ROWS. 
  ]
```

The first part is working all right - The products are being calculated properly. But how can I access these individual products to find sum of products? I could not find any way since the rows are not really objects whose public variables or methods/functions I may be able to access. How can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In `b/extra: reduce [t1 f1 t2 f2 t3 t4]`, why do you save 6 face references when you use only 3 of them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I just learned about faces and panes, here a solution without error handling

```
make-row: func [][
     compose [
        text "N1:"
        field 
        text "N2: "
        field
        text "Product: "
        text ""
        button "Get product" [
            b1: index? find face/parent/pane  face
            face/parent/pane/(b1 - 1)/text:  form multiply   to-integer   face/parent/pane/(b1 - 5)/text  to-integer face/parent/pane/(b1 - 3)/text  
        ]

    ]  
]
view compose [
    (make-row) return 
    (make-row) return
    button "Calculate" [
        t2/text:   form add to-integer face/parent/pane/6/text  to-integer face/parent/pane/13/text
    ]
    text "Sum of products:"
    t2: text ""  
]
```

All face objects are ordered in the pane block of the parent face. So looking at the index of the clicked face object you get a reference to compute the position of  other face objects.

Comment: Some explanation on how it is working will be appreciated.

Comment: Btw @rnso, I noticed you reformatted the indentation and brackets in a lispy style. Check the red standard here: https://github.com/red/red/wiki/Coding-Style-Guide#block-layouts

Comment: I did'nt know there is an official style for Red language. Lispy style mainly saves space (almost empty lines).

Comment: @rnso By the looks of it, the calculations are done based on the proximity of faces to button clicked (see the line `find face/parent/pane face`). Remember that once created, faces are merely objects structured in a hierarchical way where the usual rules of Red apply. You can see this here: `view [text "Some" text "Words" text "In" text "A" text "Window" button "Remove" [remove face/parent/pane]]`